# Combine worksheets into one workbook w/ VBA Excel Macro; Issues with macOS?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've been trying to follow the below instructions (among several other guides on SO and online) to run an Excel macro to combine several .xls files into one .xlsx workbook. I'm using macOS and Microsoft Excel for Mac 16.16.1.

[Combine Multiple Excel Workbooks into one Workbook with multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160286/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-one-workbook-with-multiple-sheets)

[Code from link reproduced below, edited path only:]

```
Option Explicit
Const path As String = "/Users/mbpro/Desktop/Project Work/Excel Sheets"
Sub GetSheets()
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet

FileName = Dir(path & "*.xls*")
Do While FileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    For Each sheet In wb.Sheets
        sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next sheet
    wb.Close
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

After I point the path to my folder containing the .xls files this script (and closely-related scripts) runs such that `path` is assigned (and `Dir()` evaluates to) an empty string. Because macros are definitely enabled I believe Excel has trouble finding the path even though I've specified the same directory string that appears when I navigate to the folder and output 'pwd' in Terminal.

Stepping through instructions in the VBA window, FileName just gets assigned to an empty string. Why is Excel having trouble finding the directory? I don't believe it's a syntax issue, is it some internal macOS access control issue?

Comment: On Mac, `Dir()` doesn't support wildcards like `*`

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm